# Is it possible to turn off drawing the UI during the next run loop cycle?

Tags: ios

Is there any way I can temporarily disable the drawing of the UI (and the progression of animations and other related things)?

I have a notification system which coalesces notifications, so that multiple notifications which happen in a single run loop cycle are coalesced into one for the interested party, kind of like how `setNeedsDisplay` can be called any number of times in a single cycle, but the drawing only happens once.

The problem is, the way I'm coalescing notifications is to schedule the forward notification on the next run loop, and skip new updates in the meantime, kind of like this:

```
private var startedCoalescingUpdates = false

func receiveNotification() {
    guard startedCoalescingUpdates == false else {
        return
    }

    startedCoalescingUpdates = true

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.setForwardNotification = false

        self.delegate.updateOccurred()
    }
}
```

Notifications can be chained together, so that one notification triggers another notification, which can trigger another, etc.

Because `OperationQueue.main.addOperation` happens on the next cycle (or at least it does if I call it from another block which was scheduled in `addOperation`), some UI drawing occurs whilst the notifications propagate. The UI can show several frames which look incorrect; I'd rather not draw the UI or respond to events, etc, until the notifications are all done, in order for all the data to be fully ready before its drawn for the first time. I'd probably do something like:

```
private var startedCoalescingUpdates = false

func receiveNotification() {
    guard startedCoalescingUpdates == false else {
        return
    }

    startedCoalescingUpdates = true

    //////
    stopDrawingUI()
    //////

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.setForwardNotification = false

        //////
        resumeDrawingUI()
        //////

        self.delegate.updateOccurred()
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think that isn't possible. A solution to your problem could be avoiding view updates in several run loop cycles. Instead you should process your notifications in the background. If one decides to update the view, it should send a single update operation to the main thread.

Comment: @macmoonshine The problem is that the updates could happen in response to a user action. Unfortunately, this might mean a new view controller is pushed without its content appearing for a few frames.

Comment: Your requirements sound somewhat contradictory. You can't display new view controller with complete content, while your data is still incomplete. A workaround could be the display of an activity indicator instead.